# How to create and merge dataframes on the fly?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have 10 csv files which are huge in size. I would like to

1) read those files

2) create dataframes (with filename as dataframe name)

3) left outer join all of them based on joining keys which are given. `POIU and 
BVCX have only one common column to merge which is A` . Please note file 'ABCDE' is the base df.. All other dataframe should be left outer joined with this 'ABCDE' df. It is possible that there are other common keys as well. But I would like to join based on keys `A` and `B` whichever of these two exist

[image]

I was able to do the first two steps as shown below

```
filenames = sorted(glob.glob('*.csv'))
df_list=[]
for f in filenames:
    print(f)
    t = vars()['df'+ f = pd1.read_csv(f,low_memory=False)
    df_list.append(t)
```

But I am stuck on how to **left outer join** all this on the fly and create one final dataframe which will be named as `df_final`?

Comment: What is *left outer merge*? I know *left merge* and *outer merge*.

Comment: Isn't there anything like left outer join?

Comment: File 'ABCDE' is the base dataframe. All other dataframe should be left joined to this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the joining keys are all the shared keys that exists in the files, you don't have to do anything special to change from one joined key to 2.
You can merge them in the loop with:

```
for f in filenames:

    # YOUR CODE WITH WHATEVER YOU DO WITH IT
    print(f)
    t = vars()['df'+ f = pd1.read_csv(f,low_memory=False)
    df_list.append(t)

    # THE CODE FOR MERGING THE DFS
    cur_df = pd1.read_csv(f, low_memory=False)
    try:
        JKeys = ['A', 'B'] if 'B' in cur_df.columns else ['A']:
        df_final = df_final.merge(cur_df, right_on=JKeys, how='left')
    except:
        df_final = cur_df
```

Comment: But in this, how do we identify `ABCDE` is the base dataframe?. it's missing

Comment: All the dataframes  might have other common column names as well but I would like to left outer join only based on keys `A` and `B`. please note that there are two df that doesn't have keys `B`

Comment: I've added a line to define the keys on which to merge. Please take into notice that if you have common columns in the dataframes that you are NOT merging on, you will end up with two columns for each, one for each dataframe it
 came from. 
And 'ABCDE' is the first dataframe, isn't it?

Comment: Thanks. Checking. Will try tonight. traveling. But quick question. Don't we have to start left join from `ABCDE`? As this is the base dataframe, we should left join all other tables to this. Right? Am thinking from an sql prespective

Comment: Correct. The `except` section will take the first `df` to `df_final`, and all the other dfs would be `left joined` to it in the `try` section.

Comment: Ahh okay. You are assuming it in the order. But what if `ABCDE` appears as 5th file in the list of files?

Comment: If you want to merge all the others to its left, then you have to have it in the first merge anyhow. Otherwise, what would you do in the first `merge` with two other files, without knowing what you would need later on when you do have 'ABCDE'? It's really not a problem to create a new `filenames` list, who has 'ABCDE' as the first item, even if in the original list it was 5th or somthing. For example you can do: `filenames = ['ABCDE'] + [f for f in filenames if f != 'ABCDE']` to be sure it is now first.

Comment: I didn't know this. Anyway. now it makes sense. Got it. Will update the answer soon

Comment: @SSMK I droped it. I don't work with `pyspark`, and it didn't give me an error, but I see it works without it anyway.